# Why doesn't the function return the value?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return, return-value

I wrote this piece of code, why doesn't the first function return the value of the second one when I put it (consolePlay()) in the console?

```
function computerPlay() {
    getRandomIntInclusive(1, 3)
}

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

Comment: Because it doesn't have a `return` statement.

Comment: Because you don't tell it to...  `return getRandomInInclusive(1, 3)`.

Comment: And you need to actually call `computerPlay` and log the returned value. You clearly understand how `return` works in the second function but somehow didn't extrapolate that to the first function.

Comment: @Andy @Scott @Barmar But isn't the return already in the second function? If I call     `getRandomIntInclusive(1, 3)` isn't it the same of putting `return Math.floor...`?

Comment: @CyberM Well that `return` returns from `getRandomIntInclusive()`. It doesn't return from `computerPlay()`.

Comment: Your question was "Why doesn't the function return the value?". The answer, as Barmar pointed out, is that your first function doesn't return anything.

Comment: `return` applies to the block that it it is in. It does not get inherited by the caller. So the answer is, add the missing return.

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning anything. Simply add the return keyword and it will work as expected

```js
function computerPlay() {
    return getRandomIntInclusive(1, 3)
}
```